# How to get the query params for the axios call in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

**HelloWorld.vue**

```js
import axios from "axios";
export const deploymentattribute = ({ serv, id }) =>
  axios.get( api cal here .................
    
  );
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(attribute, index) in attributes" :key="index">
      {{ attribute.att }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import { deploymentattribute } from "./deploymentattribute";
export default {
  name: "DeploymentAttributeView",
  data() {
    return {
      attributes: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    const response = await deploymentattribute({
      servicetype: this.$route.query.ser,
      id: this.$route.query.id,
    });
    this.attributes = response.data;
  },
};
</script>
```

Issue with the code above, I'm unable to get the query string params dynamically. Getting as `undefined`

Is there any way to pass them dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have

```js
import axios from "axios";
export const deploymentattribute = ({ servicetype, id }) =>
  axios.get(
    `http://10.11.12.13:3000/servicedetail/?servicetype=${servicetype}&id=${id}`
  );
```

and

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(attribute, index) in attributes" :key="index">
      {{ attribute.attribute }}
      {{ attribute.value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import { deploymentattribute } from './deploymentattribute'
export default {
  name: "DeploymentAttributeView",
  data() {
    return {
      attributes: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    const response = await deploymentattribute({ servicetype: this.$route.query.servicetype, id: this.$route.query.id })
    this.attributes = response.data
  },
};
</script>
```

Because you don't have the `this` context by default in a `js` file.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243436/discussion-on-answer-by-kissu-how-to-get-the-query-params-for-the-axios-call-in).

Answer (score 1):

Get the params id either by:

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id = urlParams.id;
```

or

```
 const id = this.$route.query.id;
```

Then instead of quotes use template literal to use variable value inside a string:

```
export const deploymentattribute = ({ servicetype, id }) =>
 

  axios.get(`http://example.com/servicedetail/?servicetype=. {servicetype}&id=${id}`);

 );
```